# How to dynamically create sequence generators in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to reuse Counter by passing the sequence name `order_sequence` dynamically to this class, how can this be achieved

```
public class Counter  {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence-generator")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "sequence-generator", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator", parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "order_sequence"),
            @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"), @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1") })
    private Long counter;

}
```

Comment: what do you mean under "reuse"? Do you want to define JPA annotations in MappedSuperClass and define particular sequence in child classes?

Comment: yes, I want to reuse the Counter definition but pass in the variable sequence_name and other values as dynamic parameter from extended child classes

Comment: what db engine you use oracle or mysql etc..?

Comment: why do you need this? Having static sequences defined for you db and inside your entities is way easier to understand also way easier to do. There is no point I can think of where this will come in handy and fix a problem you might face. And even speaking of that: Do not fix problems which are not there!

Answer (score 1):

The main idea could be override `org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator` in the following way:

```java
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface EntityAwareGeneratorParams {

    String sequence();

}
```

```java
public class EntityAwareGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator {

    public static final String NAME = EntityAwareGenerator.class.getName();

    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {
        String entityName = params.getProperty(ENTITY_NAME);
        if (entityName == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Entity name must not be null");
        }

        Class<?> entityClass = serviceRegistry.requireService(ClassLoaderService.class)
                .classForName(entityName);

        EntityAwareGeneratorParams generatorParams = entityClass.getAnnotation(EntityAwareGeneratorParams.class);
        if (generatorParams == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format(
                    "Annotation @%s is not present for class %s",
                    EntityAwareGeneratorParams.class.getName(),
                    entityClass.getName()
            ));
        }

        params.setProperty(SEQUENCE_PARAM, generatorParams.sequence());

        super.configure(type, params, serviceRegistry);
    }

}
```

MappedSuperClass:

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "entity-aware-generator", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@GenericGenerator(name = "entity-aware-generator", strategy = EntityAwareGenerator.NAME, ...)
private Long id;
```

Child classes:

```
@Entity
@EntityAwareGeneratorParams(sequence="another sequence")
```